# Importing 1000s of svg symbols into QGIS 2.18

Tags: symbology, import, classification, xml, svg

Does anyone know a way to import 1000s of svg symbols into QGIS without having to painstakingly click on every single XML file to import?  I created SVG files (with xml) of all of the CAMUTCD sign symbols for CA, but it is so painful in QGIS to bring them all in and associate them automatically to the "class" classification in a categorized style process.

I would like to automate the process so it points to the svg directory in QGIS and in style have it automatically find the catagorized "class" value which is identical to the name of the SVG symbol.